# Does Facebook provide message API for application developer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know that can we ask the user permission to send them message from our program on Facebook. Does Facebook provide that kind of API?

Comment: There is the Notifications API – but that is only available to apps with a Canvas implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chat API is deprecated and there is no alternative: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

You can use the Send Dialog, no authorization or additional permissions needed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: Does Android or IOS provide that ChatAPI for Facebook?